# CSS não carrega com $_SESSION

Tags: php, html5

Carrego o CSS dessa forma:

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Mas gostaria de passar uma referencia difente, algo como:

```
 <link href="<?php echo $_SESSION['caminho_completo']."css/style.css"?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Mas quando faço isso o CSS não carrega na página, qual solução teria para isto?
obs: funciona na home.php que está dentro da pasta paginas, mas não funciona para os arquivos que estão dentro da pasta 1998.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: _"da primeira forma também não está carregando, acredito que é algum problema com o caminho"_ ... Primeiro precisa acertar o caminho, depois resolver a questão da sessão, senão fica difícil até de você testar. Seria bom [edit] a questão e por o trecho de HTML resultante do seu segundo exemplo.

Comment: se eu conseguir resolver sem usar a sessão vai ser bom

Comment: Já experimentou colocar o caminho desde a raiz? (começando pela barra):   `/caminho/completo/css/style.css` - E antes de testar no <link> tente ao menos acessar direto pelo navegador, digitando o endereço na barra de endereço. Por exemplo, se seu site é `http://example.com` e você consegue acessar seu CSS por `http://example.com/assets/css/style.css`, o caminho desde a raiz seria: `href="/assets/css/style.css"`

Comment: @Bacco por isso que eu tentei usar a session, pra passar o caminho completo, mas não deu certo. consigo acessar o CSS com esse link "http://localhost/PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA/css/style.css"

Comment: Dá uma olhada no código fonte (CTRL+u) e veja o que aparece onde tem a SESSION. Assim vc verifica que valor está passando e se o caminho está correto.

Comment: @dvd o caminho fica assim: <link href="C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
 não sei se teria algum problema as barras ficarem invertidas. O caminho está correto

Comment: Tem problema sim. Vc quer linkar do servidor local para um arquivo no computador?

Comment: não sei se entendi muito bem o que vc quis dizer... Mas a intenção é usar o CSS nas minhas páginas do sistema

Comment: Nos arquivos  dentro da pasta "paginas" o caminho deve ser "../css/style.css", nos da pasta "1998" deve ser "../../css/style.css"

Comment: o problema é que ele está dentro do header.php e o mesmo é incluído em todos os arquivos: include("header.php"), tanto no home que está dentro de paginas quanto nos arquivos que estão dentro de 1998

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você tenha um arquivo de config no seu projeto, caso não tenha fica a sugestão de criar um, nele você pode definir variaveis e constantes para usar no teu projeto, exemplo:

**config.php**

```
define('_LINK_BASE_', "http://exemplo.com.br");
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once('config.php'); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="<?php echo _LINK_BASE_; ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: eu estava fazendo o define no meu index.php, mas quando tentava usar em algum local diferente acusava undefined , por isso parti para a session, mas basicamente o meu header.php é o config... ao invés do endereço eu colocava __ DIR __

Comment: __ DIR __ retorna o diretório do arquivo atual equivalente a  dirname(__ FILE __), tenta definir o caminho completo no braço mesmo, se usar sempre a constante, quando for colocar em produção só via alterar essa constante.

Comment: vai ser um sistema interno, vai ficar num servidor aqui